# ssh login information

Tags: 12.04, networking, command-line, ssh

As the admin of my machine, I want users to be able to log into my computer with ssh, but I'm looking for a graphical way to be notified that a user is connected at the moment. If multiple users are connected, I want a list of connected users, their location, name, etc. This could be in the form of a forceCommand and 'alert' command when someone logs in, plus a icon saying how many people are connected right now in the notification bar, with the option to click on it to have more information about these users.

Is there such a tool available in ubuntu, and if not, how to do it (I'm guessing it's not that difficult and could be done with under ten bash command lines) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember doing something like this.

I used gkrellm, it comes with a simple proc/users chart, you can go into the settings and tell it to run whatever command you want when you click its button.

It won't give you a list of usernames by default, but I made a simple bash script to pipe w to a file, open it in gedit, and remove the temp file.  Worked for what I needed it for.